# Jacoco : Excluding classes and methods using ant - class list and method list is in prop file

Tags: ant, jacoco

I am new to jacoco and ant...

I am trying to generate jacoco coverage report using ant script by excluding classes
and methods which seems to be not working.

I've a bunch of jar files which i've included in  task like :

```
<fileset id="a" dir="ABC">
   <include name="A123.jar"/>
   <include name="A456.jar"/>
</fileset>
<fileset id="b" dir="DEF">
   <include name="D123.jar"/>
</fileset>
<fileset id="c" dir="GHI">
  <include name="G123.jar"/>
</fileset>

for exclude i have added :
<fileset id="exclude" dir=".">
  <excludesfile name="jacoco_class_filter.txt"/>
  <excludesfile name="jacoco_method_filter.txt"/>
</fileset>
```

....

now i have a bunch of classes/methods to be excluded while generating the report and     these list are in a txt file:
jacoco_class_filter.txt and jacoco_method_filter.txt

format for class filter is : 
        **/packagename/classname*
format for method filter is : 
        **/package/class/method*

In jacoco report task I have added :

```
<jacoco:report ..
 <structure name="code coverage">
  <group name="codecov 1">
   <classfiles>
     <fileset refid="a"/>
   </classfiles>
 </group>
```

...
...contd for b and c.
when i run this report gets generated but along with unwanted class/methods.

Now issue is how do i exclude the class/method from txt file.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Code coverage metrics are generated by running a test suite. To exclude code that is not working, then don't invoke the tests that call that code.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I want to exclude the dev code which is not called by our tests. Our automation covers most of dev code but there are some class/methods which still shows up in coverage report.Along with those there are other 3rdparty packages added in report which i want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

In jacoco:report task put the following:

```
 <fileset refid="a">
     <exclude name="**/example_directory/*"/>     
 </fileset>
```